# Effect of magnetic field on energy gap of semiconductors like diode,transistors

Tags: semiconductors

I am doing my project on energy gap of semiconductors. For that i have an doubt that what will happen to the energy gap of diode if it is exposed to magnetic field intensity?
Is it possible to place diode circuit in the magnetic field?
If yes what is the relationship between enrgy gap and magnetic field. How can it calculated?

Comment: Small effects can be seen with practical magnetic fields, but at unachievably high field, it gets... gnarly.   <https://infogalactic.com/info/Hofstadter%27s_butterfly>

Answer (score 0):

Charge carriers in a semiconductor exposed to a magnetic field are influenced by the [Hall effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect), but the effects on a typical diode are negligible. The effect can only be practically detected with specially designed Hall effect sensors; even then, powerful amplifiers are required.

Comment: What is relation between energy gap and magnetic field?

Comment: @Dhayalan As duskwuff sayed it is determined by the hall-effect. read up on hall-effect and it will make sense.

Comment: @Vinzent The Hall Effect relates to the curved (rather than straight) path that electrons follow in the presence of a magnetic field oriented to cause that effect. It's not a panacea explanation of the effect of magnetic fields -- and certainly not an explanation of the effect -- on the *energy gap*. (It may matter at very low temps, though.) That subject would be based far more upon *different* physical principles; Fermi surface, Shroedinger equation, Landau quantizations, and perhaps others. But Hall Effect would be low on my list, anyway.